# What IDS Do you recommend?

Tags: ids, mod-security, snort

I am running a Debian Squeeze VPS and need a good IDS. I have used snort before and it was quite good but i am wandering if there are any other good ones out there.

Preferably compatible with modsecurity.

Comment: Shopping questions are discouraged on all Stack Exchange sites as not constructive - answers will be subjective.

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer OSSEC. It is a free, open source tool backed up with commercial support.

Answer (score 0):

a lot of IDS tools are on the internet and one of them is Suricata  and here are comparison between it and snort [Suricata vs Snort](http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Suricata-vs-snort)
and there a lot of others like security onion,Smooth-Sec ,Alienvault OSSIM .....etc

Also commerical versions are available